Routing in MVC ASP.NET Core with Controllers and Views
I'm still trying to explore the Routing but I couldn't get the job done. I get confused on how do I use the Views and Controllers, I am trying to achieve like http://localhost:5036/Dashboard/Products because I'm creating a CRUD app but trying in different Routes but it is popping up an error and the only thing I can think of is that about the file path or the Controllers.
I have an sample image for which the Products is inside the Dashboard.
Dashboard
First I have the _DashboardLayout.cshtml
...
<ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Dashboard" asp-action="Index">
            Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Products"
            asp-action="Index">Products</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Products"
            asp-action="Create">Create Product</a>
    </li>
</ul>
...

And the Controller/ProductsController.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Crud.Entities;
using Crud.Models;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Crud.Controllers.Dashboard
{
    // [Route("Dashboard/[controller]")]
    public class ProductsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext _context;

        public ProductsController(AppDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Dashboard/Products
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var products = await _context.Products.ToListAsync();
            return View("Dashboard/Products/Index", products);
        }

        // GET: Dashboard/Products/Create
        [HttpGet("Create")]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View("Dashboard/Products/Create");
        }

        // POST: Dashboard/Products/Create
        [HttpPost("Create")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,ProductName,ProductBrand, Quantity, TypeOfProduct, Price, AgeRange")] Product product)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(product);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View("Dashboard/Products/Create", product);
        }

        // GET: Dashboard/Products/Edit/5
        [HttpGet("Edit/{id:int}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null) return NotFound();
            var product = await _context.Products.FindAsync(id);
            if (product == null) return NotFound();
            return View("Dashboard/Products/Edit", product);
        }

        // POST: Dashboard/Products/Edit/5
        [HttpPost("Edit/{id:int}")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,ProductName,ProductBrand, Quantity, TypeOfProduct, Price, AgeRange")] Product product)
        {
            if (id != product.Id) return NotFound();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(product);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!ProductExists(product.Id)) return NotFound();
                    throw;
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View("Dashboard/Products/Edit", product);
        }

        // GET: Dashboard/Products/Delete/5
        [HttpGet("Delete/{id:int}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null) return NotFound();
            var product = await _context.Products.FindAsync(id);
            if (product == null) return NotFound();
            return View("Dashboard/Products/Delete", product);
        }

        // POST: Dashboard/Products/Delete/5
        [HttpPost("Delete/{id:int}")]
        [ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var product = await _context.Products.FindAsync(id);
            _context.Products.Remove(product);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool ProductExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Products.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}


And the DashboardController.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

using System.Diagnostics;
using Crud.Models;

namespace Crud.Controllers
{
    public class DashboardController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            // Add any additional logic for the dashboard here
            return View(); // Return the dashboard view
        }


        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }


    }
}

And this are the error I keep receiving. After clicking in the _DashboardLayout.cshtml links
Error 1
Error 2

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

@LeonhardMeinhard: When using images try to keep the resolution to show information in readable form and don't reduce the picture quality like on the the first screenshot.

you can set exact location of your view with
return View("~/Views/yourPath.cshtml")

or you can read this
link

By default ASP.Net will search for your view in the location "Views/{ControllerName}/{ViewName}". Thats where the "Views/Products"-Part comes from.
Also when returning the viewpath, you are using a relative path "Dashboard/Products/Index". This will be interprated as the viewname-part of the default search location.
There are multiple solutions:

Consider moving your views to the default location. Then instead of returning the path to view, all you need to do is return View("Index", products);
As suggested from @Juju Lian, you could return a virtual path i.e. return View("~/Views/Dashboard/Products/Index", products);

